# Problems pasting text into Visual Studio from other programs

Tags: copy-paste, visual-studio

I'm using Visual Studio Express 2013 for Web. Any guidance on fixing or troubleshooting this would be greatly appreciated. Here's what I know today.

- I've rebooted. I also repaired Visual Studio.
- I cannot paste text from Notepad or Chrome into Visual Studio. If I try to the cursor jumps to the previous position it was at before I tried pasting!?! Something is happening but the outcome is wrong.
- I can paste text that was copied from within Visual Studio into Visual Studio.
- I can paste from one Visual Studio process to another one.
- I can paste text that was copied from Word 2013 into Visual Studio.
- I can paste from Visual Studio to Word, Notepad, Chrome.
- I can paste between other programs, Notepad to Word 2013 and vice versa, for example.

Comment: Start your computer with a minimal startup configration

Comment: @Ramhound I was very much hoping your suggestion would help me discover an interfering program, but the problem persists after following these [clean boot instructions](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/929135).

Comment: It has helped you.  You have narrowed it down to the application that start with even the minimal startup configuration.  That decreases the possible choices by a good amount.  For instance there is a good 50-60 process different between a normal startup and a minimal startup in most of my devices.

Comment: Good point. I'm surprised by this outcome since I am not running any special Visual Studio extensions, only the defaults that come with Visual Studio Express 2013 for Web Update 4. I will try uninstalling those one by one to see if it makes a difference. @Ramhound do you have any other suggestions at this point?

Answer (score 0):

The source of my issue was Webroot Application Protection. Apparently it watches the clipboard and prevents pasting to certain applications. In my case, Application Protection defaulted to denying pasting to Visual Studio. **Changing the setting for vwdexpress.exe to either Allow or Protect permits pasting to VS.**

The moral of the story for me is to be mindful when installing security software. You never know what unexpected side-effects it might have. It also likely won't be disabled when clean booting.

[image: Webroot Application Protection denies pasting to Visual Studio]